# Chrome extension won't update

Tags: chrome-web-store

I'm making a Chrome extension. Right now, it's only available to test users. Some of the test users can access it, but some just get a "404" page. Also, when I try to update the code (uploading a new zip to the extensions), it acts like it updates. But when I go to the Web store page, it still lists the old version. It says it might "take a few minutes" for changes to publish, but it's been days and they still aren't published.

Comment: This is not related to the actual development. You can report the web store bugs to some official Google product forum  like [this one](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions).

Comment: Oh gotcha, thanks! They helped. Do you know if there is something like that for Facebook login by chance? There's an official Developer Community Forum, but it's not very active.